# Directshow support for 4K resolution

Tags: image, directshow

We have a 4k frame grabber which can capture 4K images. Our current setup is on x64 Windows 7. It is possible to capture 4K images with Directshow (can be any version)?

Is there a way to over come the limitation of The dwBitRate(DWORD , 32 bit) inside VIDEOINFOHEADER which will overflow for 4K data. For example (2160x3840x23x32) bitspersecond.

Comment: Maybe you can get away with setting the bitrate to maxuint32. It is documented as `Approximate data rate of the video stream, in bits per second`. For compressed data the bitrate can be important to tell the encoder what to do, but for uncompressed it is useless, as it can be simply calculated.

Comment: Bitrate for raw formats is optional, there are no problems really with 4k support.